# JSESSIONID not passed through HTTP cookie Manage in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, ruby-jmeter

Through JMeter is not able to pass the JSESSIONID although it happens very rarely, I am not able to find out the root cause.

My first request is login - POST on HTTPS protocol
Next request is using the JSESSIONID of the first request as i have added HTTP Cookie Manager from the Config Element, this request is GET over HTTPS and its giving 401 status code.
And the login successfully happened.

Anyone, please suggest ???

Comment: Is the domain (Server) of the first request and second request the same? P.S. HTTP 401 means, that sever required HTTP authentication (not the JSESSION ID).

Comment: Yes both are over https protocol only, it means its giving http status code as 401